# An Introduction to the Theory of Groups 1.13

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

The question asks: if $\alpha$ is an $n$-cycle, then $\alpha^k$ is a product of $gcd(n, k)$ disjoint cycles, each of length $n/gcd(n, k)$.

I am not quite sure how to proceed with the problem, because we know that $\alpha^k(a_i)=a_{i+k}$, where subscripts are read "mod $n$" but this doesn't quite get us there. We either need to have some way of finding the number of disjoint cycles and proceeding from there, or we need to be able to compute the length of each disjoint cycle and then show that these lengths will all be the same.

Lastly, I do know that $\frac{nk}{gcd(n, k)} = lcm(n, k)$ and this might be the easier quantity to work with, although I haven't quite figured out how to introduce it to the problem.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you already know that every permutation of a finite set can be written as a product of disjoint cycles? And that the order of the element that is written as a product of disjoint cycles is the LCM of the lengths of the cycles?

Comment: @Gregory I'm still not sure how to proceed from here. On the one hand, this helps if we know the length of each disjoint cycle. On the other hand, it doesn't seem like we can get the number of disjoint cycles from this approach.